# WML instead of PDF, can't print

Tags: printing

This is a self-answered question. A client with two independent providers who they download PDFs from and then print *both* started to give `WML` file extensions instead of `PDF` extensions and were unable to print the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a file association between the PDF reader (e.g. Adobe Reader or Foxit reader) was the solution. It's still the same PDF file (internal headers and all), the only difference is the file extension.

An additional problem occurred where I was unable to create an association between the WML files in Firefox to Foxit Reader for the client. I went to Windows Explorer, `open the WML file with` and created a Windows association. Then I renamed the `mimeTypes.rdf` file and opened Firefox again (you must restart Firefox). I was then able to create the association for the WML file to Foxit. I also disabled safe mode and the print dialog came up (Safe Mode in Foxit prevents JavaScript from running but if it's a trusted source then you're good).

`C:\Users\[Windows User]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[Firefox Profile Name]\mimeTypes.rdf`

This may be a bit more technical than the person searching for the answer may encounter and I'm not sure if it's limited to the health industry though it was a fairly easy fix to get it all working. Hopefully this will save someone the time and insanity of figuring out the issue.

I would recommend when contacting the provider to let them know to let their developers know that it is very likely a third-party problem since my client said that *two* independent companies started having this problem at the same time. This is what happens when either developers get lazy and just third-party the crap out of everything or bosses don't allot sufficient time for developers to do their job.